# WiFi keep disconnecting?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

**Driver**: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235

**Laptop**: NP550P5C-S05IN

**Operating System**: Win-10

I have been using this laptop for quite some time now and had no problem at all till some time back. I had to format my laptop and re-install Windows-10 due to malware. I was using my college's WiFi earlier too and there was no problem then.

But after re-installing windows again my WiFi don't work properly any more. That is: it continuously get connected and disconnected to WiFi. As I am in college so we have our accounts to log-in to access the internet, we use Cyberoam here. What happen is I will log-in into my Cyberoam account then after using internet for 5-10 minutes it will get disconnected, then I will have to switch WiFi on-off or try refreshing again and again. My laptop works fine with every other network.

I have tried re-allocating the IP address using : netsh int ip reset. Also I have tried re-installing windows-10 multiple times, also have re-installed drivers multiple times but no luck. I tried asking the IT department regarding this issue but alas they have no clue, they tried basic network troubleshooting but when does that ever work.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Wi-Fi problem? Not a network problem? Does this happen if you are hardwired?

Comment: I am not really sure,  it does work fine on other networks though.  I have not been able to find the reason for this  continuous disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by upgrading my driver.
I got the resolution from this thread:
https://communities.intel.com/thread/31090